# Where can I find the project templates for ASP.NET MVC 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#, templates, visual-studio-2008

I would like to edit the ASP.NET MVC templates for Visual Studio so that any new action or controller created has a specific piece of code within it by default.

For instance, I'd like to replace the generated:

```
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

with a specific coding standard we prefer to use within in my team. eg:

```
    public ActionResult About()
    { 
        try 
        {
             DoStuff();
             return View();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
             HandleException();
        }
    }
```

I've looked through the filesystem, but I cannot find anything specific that relates to the ASP.NET mvc templates. Anyone know where they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All inbuilt project templates are held in `%VS-Root%\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates`.

MVC project templates here (with my non-standard install folder) are `C:\VS2008\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033\MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev1.cs.zip` and `C:\VS2008\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\VisualBasic\Web\1033\MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev1.vb.zip`.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. Completely forgot that I had installed VS on another partition and was going mad trying look for these directories that didnt exist.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the following location:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC

[Link for ASP.NET MVC 2](http://mvcsharp.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/asp-net-mvc-2-rc-2-vs-2010-rc/) Project templates, not sure if same for ASP.NET MVC 1.0 though.